# How do you set up terminal colours in DDEV?

Tags: ddev

When I do `ddev ssh` it's all black text. How do I get standard terminal colours to show?

Comment: Assuming you're using bash, experiment in there by manually changing your bash config. It's just the shell. Then once you understand it, you can put it in .bashrc.d, etc.

Comment: Does nobody else have this working?